# Cnn + python3 + captcha

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, captcha, conv-neural-network

I've received a task: I need to write a **cnn on python3** for breaking *captcha* on my own. I can't use any completely solutions.

I've tried to found some examples, but all of them was written with external libraries.

Could you recommend some resource/book/article with same task?

Comment: check on python keras and tensorflows

Comment: also go with some image processing technique

Comment: @MidhunMohan I can't use Keras (unfortunately)

Comment: keras is just a wrapper around tensorflow or theano will you be able to use that

Comment: @MidhunMohan thanks, and could you get a link on something about it?

Comment: okay start with pyimagesearch blog, and the move on to machinelearning mastery those are best site for beginners as well as pro

Comment: @MidhunMohan thank you

Comment: welcome please make sure that next time you ask a question you have a good research